# Imagestyle not being created

Tags: views, 8, theming

I'm on **Core 8.7.7**
I have a content type: "**events**"
They have fields: "**Date**" and "**Image**"

Events get displayed in **2 lists**:

1. Past events (a view) (just a block showing event entities) (> this is a field in the content type Events)
2. Related events (this is an entity reference field)

Both events listed in the Past events and Related events list have the same view type "Teaser with image" which crops and scales the image to a thumbnail.

**Problem**: Upon creating a new event, the "Related Events" list does not show the image next to the event, nor does it seem to generate the thumbnail.

**Funny workaround** (that puts the finger on the issue, most likely): If I set the date to a date in the past (to force the event to show up in the Past Events list), the thumbnail gets generated (and also shows up in the Related Events list)

Anyone an idea why this is happening ?
I was assuming that when Related Events get displayed, this triggers the "Teaser with image" view and the thumbnail gets created, but it doesn't.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! :-) We don't know your Drupal core version. And is it right, that the image derivatives in the view don't get displayed? How you configured  this view then? What is the other `just a block` for a block? Also a view?

Comment: "Related events" is (just) an "entity reference" field in the Content Type, so not even a block or a view.
"Past events" list is actually a view.
Added core version in question.

Comment: In the question title the problem is in a block, in the question body Related events is a view and in the comment it is not even a block or a view. And if it is one of those we need to know how it is built or configured.

Comment: @4k4 corrected (you are right - I got mighty confused there)